# How to properly test JavaFX-View using Junit4

Tags: java, javafx, junit4

I'd like to test a universal view for a JavaFX-[Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) using Junit4. The basic setup I'm using is taken from [here](http://awhite.blogspot.ch/2013/04/javafx-junit-testing.html). (I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429422/basic-junit-test-for-javafx-8) approach, same result). The problem is that the test thread seems to "run" through the `testDummyTask` method and once it has reached the end of the test function, it immediately tears down everything. Hence, the stage is only visible for a split second before it disappears again, even though the task is not finished yet.

The test class is defined as follows:

```
@RunWith(JavaFxJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class TaskBarControllerTest {

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {

}

@Test
public void testDummyTask () throws IOException {
    final TaskBarController tskBrC = new TaskBarController(new DummyTask());
    tskBrC.start();
}


class DummyTask extends Task {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        final int ITER = 50;
        int iterations;
        for (iterations = 0; iterations < ITER; iterations++) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                updateMessage("Cancelled");
                break;
            }
            updateMessage("Iteration " + iterations);
            updateProgress(iterations, ITER);

            // Now block the thread for a short time, but be sure
            // to check the interrupted exception for cancellation!
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException interrupted) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    updateMessage("Cancelled");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

The method TaskBarController.start() is defined as follows:

```
public void start() throws IOException {
    logger.entering(this.getClass().getName(), "start()");
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(TASKBAR_FXML_RES));
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    loader.setController(this);
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.show();

    lblProcess.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    pgBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    btnCancel.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            task.cancel();
        }
    });
    task.progressProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number, Number number2) {
            lblEta.setText(getEta(number.doubleValue()));
        }
    });
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDeamon(true);
    th.start();
    logger.exiting(this.getClass().getName(), "start()");
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: CountDownLatch is your friend in this case.  Call await in your test and countDown in your dummy task to make the test wait for the task to be completed.

Comment: The problem is that when I call `await()` in the test, the javafx-thread is blocked which means that the GUI is not going to be updated.