# Cannot initialize textarea for Junit

Tags: junit, javafx, textarea

Hello fellow stackoverflow-ers

I'm writing a junit test for a method that adds text to a Javafx textarea - this textarea needs to be initialized for the test.  In a normal class I would use

```
@FXML
private TextArea myTextArea;
```

for the textarea - how do I initialize it for the test - this way I've shown above does not work and

```
TextArea myTextArea = new TextArea();
```

in the setup does not work either. I'm getting a NullPointerException for both on the line in the method to be tested that sets a string in myTextArea. Anyone got any ideas? I am probably missing something obvious.

MyClassTest.java

```
@Test
public void testDisplay {
    MyClass myClass = new myClass();
    myClass.display();
}
```

MyClass.java

```
public void display() {
    myTextArea.setText("The result of this is ....");
}
```

- MyClass is the controller for the fxml which contains the TextArea

I also use

```
@ClassRule
public JavaFXThreadingRule javafxRule = new JavaFXThreadingRule();
```

in my code - but it's still not working

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow...need to see more code!

Comment: Thanks @Nilesh - i've added more code - let me know if you need any more

Comment: Is `MyClass` the controller for fxml which contains `TextArea` ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha yes that MyClass is the controller for the fxml that contains the TextArea

Answer (score 1):

Though, I am not well-versed with JUnit testing in JavaFX, the most probable reason why you are not able to do this is because your test cases need to be on the JavaFX Application thread and your controller needs to load the FXML and the controls written inside it, before you can get the reference to `myTextArea`, which is why you are getting a `NullPointerException`

There are some pretty nice libraries which you can use for writing JUnit test cases for JavaFX

- [JemmyFX](https://jemmy.java.net/JemmyFXGuide/jemmy-guide.html)
- [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX)
- [Automaton](https://github.com/renatoathaydes/Automaton) - Used for both Swing and JavaFX

There is also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429422/basic-junit-test-for-javafx-8) which talks about writing test cases in JavaFX

Comment: Thanks ItachiUchiha I will have a look at those.                I should have mentioned earlier that I use                                                        @ClassRule
public JavaFXThreadingRule javafxRule = new JavaFXThreadingRule();                         in my code and it still does not work.