# Can we write JUnits for JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, junit

I am currently working on a javafx project. I want to write the JUnit test cases for it how can i write it?
I am really not sure about writing the junit test cases for it?
I can do functional testing but not sure about writing JUnit.
Suppose I have a below method :

```
@FXML
public void makeDeviceContentsEditable() {

    ObservableList<TextField> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(vehicleId, vehicleName, deviceType,
            offboardBroker1, offboardBroker2, postfixQueue, pKIServer);
    if (editDeviceContents.isSelected() && devicePlugged) {
        isDeviceSideEnabled();
        for (final TextField tf : list) {
            tf.setEditable(true);
            tf.setStyle(GREY_OUT_REMOVED);
            final String originalval = tf.getText();
            tf.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue,
                        String newValue) {
                    //if (!originalval.isEmpty() && originalval != null & isWritten) {
                    if (originalval != null && !originalval.isEmpty() && isWritten) {
                        tf.setStyle(CHANGED_TXT_COLOR);
                        if (newValue.equalsIgnoreCase(originalval)) {
                            tf.setStyle(NORMAL_COLOR);
                        }
                        if (tf.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("vehicleId")) {
                            editedValuesMap.put(0, newValue);
                        } else if (tf.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("vehicleName")) {
                            editedValuesMap.put(1, newValue);
                        } else if (tf.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("deviceType")) {
                            editedValuesMap.put(2, newValue);
                        } else if (tf.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("offboardBroker1")) {
                            editedValuesMap.put(3, newValue);
                        } else if (tf.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("offboardBroker2")) {
                            editedValuesMap.put(4, newValue);
                        } else if (tf.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("postfixQueue")) {
                            editedValuesMap.put(5, newValue);
                        } else if (tf.getId().equalsIgnoreCase("pKIServer")) {
                            editedValuesMap.put(6, newValue);
                        }
                    }
                    maxTextFieldLengthCheck(tf, newValue);
                }
            });
        }

    } else if (!editDeviceContents.isSelected()) {
        for (final TextField tf : list) {
            tf.setEditable(false);
        }
        textfieldStyle(TEXTFIELD_GREY_OUT);
        bWriteToDevice.setDisable(true);
    }
    //isWritten=false;
}
```

Comment: Can you check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429422/basic-junit-test-for-javafx-8

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the mentioned question, and try it out. If you have further issues, post a new question with the concrete problem you are facing.