# Test JavaFX Applications by using JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, javafx, junit

I want to test javaFX application by using junit. I checked several approaches as follow:

1. user TestFX api: these api works sometime on a test method, in other word, for some execution of a special test, it's work !!!
2. List use JFXRunner : I used test runner which is defined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429422/basic-junit-test-for-javafx-8), but it for a few of the methods to be run and when number of test methods be large(e.g. >20) , test methods waiting forever !!!
3. define a test runner class such as JavaFXThreadingRule which has been intruduced in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429422/basic-junit-test-for-javafx-8). these approach works only for a single test and when run some test, test method go into waiting forever same as JFXRunner.

what is the problem really? by debugging test method, I found that by using lath for initializing javaFX, after running several method, remaining method will be waiting for ever. When I set a special time for awaiting method of lath, it work's correctly by it is not logically to set a constant time to test application. How can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for approach 2,3; I used Platform.exit() command for exiting from GUI Application; so test runner which use latch to initialize JavaFX platform wait forever. So, it was my code fault.So, calling Platform.exit() method prevents to execute remaining test methods.