# JUnit and Multithreading in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, junit4

Let's have **`Analyzer` class** that provides time-consuming **`analyze` method**.

```
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class Analyzer {
    public enum State {
        NOT_ANALYZED, ANALYZING, ANALYZED, FAILED
    }

    private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<State> stateWrapper = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(State.NOT_ANALYZED);
    private volatile int result = -1;

    public void analyze(String someText) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (stateWrapper.get() == State.ANALYZING)
                return;

            stateWrapper.set(State.ANALYZING);
        }

        Task analyzeWorker = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() {
                // Some time-consuming operations based on someText parameter

                result = 11;
                return null;
            }
        };

        analyzeWorker.setOnSucceeded(event -> stateWrapper.set(State.ANALYZED));
        analyzeWorker.setOnFailed(event -> stateWrapper.set(State.FAILED));

        (new Thread(analyzeWorker)).start();
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<State> stateProperty() {
        return stateWrapper.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
}
```

---

The caller of **`analyze` method** than listening to the **`state` property** to know if the analysis is complete.

Based on that I would like write **JUnit (4) test** like this:

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class AnalyzerTest {
    @Test
    public void resultTest() {
        Object syncObject = new Object();
        Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer();

        analyzer.stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Analyzer.State>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Analyzer.State> observable, Analyzer.State oldValue, Analyzer.State newValue) {
                    if (newValue == Analyzer.State.ANALYZED) {
                        synchronized (syncObject) {
                            syncObject.notify();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        );

        synchronized(syncObject) {
            try {
                analyzer.analyze("Some long text");
                syncObject.wait();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                fail("Intterupted Exception");
            }
        }
        assertEquals(11, analyzer.getResult());
    }
}
```

The problem is that this test will never end. I put a breakpoint inside **`analyzeWorker.call` method** that is never reached in the case of the test.

Comment: Is the JavaFX toolkit initialized when you run the test? Otherwise the FX Application Thread won't be running, so the `onSucceeded` handler won't be able to be executed... (In fact, there'll be problems earlier when the task tries to change its state to `RUNNING`, for example, which it needs to do on the FX Application Thread.) (Aside: you need to make `result` volatile.)

Comment: @James_D How can I find out, please? I use IntelliJ IDEA and run test by green-arrow button.

Comment: Well, are you doing anything to start it? Calling `Application.launch()` anywhere?

Comment: @James_D No, I think that only `resultTest` method is executed.

Comment: So I think that's the problem. I don't use JUnit for anything that requires the FX Application Thread to be running (I just unit test my controller methods and services independently): there is some information on using JUnit for JavaFX around, and IIRC a framework (JemmyFX?)

Comment: @James_D Ok, thank you. Maybe this will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18988752.

Comment: As a "quick and dirty" approach, try calling `new JFXPanel();` in a `setUp` method, and `Platform.exit()` in a `tearDown()` method

Comment: @James_D It's works, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments by James_D – in the case of the **test**, **FX Application Thread** not run automatically and must be started explicitly.

*Quick (and dirty) approach:*

```
public class AnalyzerTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        new JFXPanel();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @Test
    public void resultTest() {
        …
    }
}
```

In the case of 2 and more tests, `Platform.exit` causes an exception (*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Platform.exit has been called*), so I don't use it.