# Trying to test TextField in Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit

So I am trying to test a simple code (just to test why it won't work). Trying to test the code in the red box in first image.

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPuSr.png)

This is the message I get when i try to run the test. 
[Message from test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Om2r8.png)

Anyone know what I do wrong?

```
import gruppeeksamen.Controller.LeggTilArrangementController;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class LeggTilArrangementControllerTest {
@FXML
private TextField arrangementInput = null;
@FXML
private ComboBox idrettComboBox = null;

@Test
public void sjekkOmAlleInputErFyltUt() {
    DatePicker datoDatePicker = null;
    arrangementInput.setText("");
    datoDatePicker.setValue(null);
    idrettComboBox.setValue(null);
    LeggTilArrangementController leggTilArrangementController = new LeggTilArrangementController();
    assertTrue(leggTilArrangementController.sjekkOmAlleInputErFyltUt(arrangementInput, datoDatePicker, idrettComboBox));
}

@Test
public void sjekkeOm() {
    arrangementInput.setText("");
    assertEquals("", arrangementInput.getText());
}
```

}

Comment: Can you attach the code in question as a code and not as screenshots?

Comment: Maybe you can do that using the `JavaFXThreadingRule` as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18988752/5118762