# How to do junit test for javafx

Tags: java, javafx, junit, junit5

I was trying to run `javafx` junit test. However, I had issues with it not running the test on the javafx thread. So I did what this questions answers said to do ([Basic JUnit test for JavaFX 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429422/basic-junit-test-for-javafx-8)). However, now I'm getting this error in my junit class and I don't how to fix it

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel
    at TestJunit$1.run(TestJunit.java:26)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 2 more
```

Also heres my `junit` file if it helps.

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import Champions.autoBattleChampion;
import Model.autoBattleModel;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Rule;

public class TestJunit {


   /*
    * <== Test Model ==>
    */
   @Test
   public void testpopulateChampionStore_0() {  
       Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
               new JFXPanel(); // Initializes the JavaFx Platform
               Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                      autoBattleModel model = new autoBattleModel();
                      model.stopTimer();
                      assertEquals(1,1);

                   }
               });
           }
       });
       thread.start();// Initialize the thread
       try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // Time to use the app, with out this, the thread
                               // will be killed before you can tell.
   }
}
```

Comment: There is a unit test framework for JavaFX available [TestFX](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX).  I haven't used it, but you could try it if you like.  It would likely be a better alternative than using some info from an old blog post.  The documentation seems up-to-date with more recent versions of JavaFX (e.g. 11+), which is good because information on the execution of JavaFX 8 is quite different than later versions due to the way the module system is used with JavaFX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding these vm arguments into my junit class fixed it.

```
--module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk-17/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

Comment: It is weird that that would work because your error message is `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel`, so I would have thought you would also need to add the `javafx.swing` module.

Comment: I guess alternatives to this approach would be to include a `module-info.java` file for your test module or use a version of the JDK (e.g. liberica by bell-soft) that includes the JavaFX modules.